# How to display current time on welcome message/MOTD?

Tags: linux, centos

```
echo "Current date and time: $(date)" >> /etc/motd
```

The above code displays the current time that was added to `/etc/motd`.

I want the user to see the actual current time and date after the login. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than a one-shot time how about if the user sees the current time at each command line prompt?

Try this first from the command line prompt:

```
PS1="\@ \w$bk"
```

The prompt will look like: 11:41 AM ~

More information for the user might be to add the username and local machine name with the time. With the user "DrPete" on a local machine named "LittleSorrel" the prompt:

```
PS1="\u on \h \@ \w$bk "
```

Looks like: DrPete on LittleSorrel 10:34 AM ~

To reset the prompt to default to "# ":

```
PS1="# "
```

To make the prompt **permanently** available, add the prompt construction of your choice, i.e.,

```
export PS1="\@ \w$bk "
```

To ~/.profile.

Answer (score 0):

From this guide

https://ownyourbits.com/2017/04/05/customize-your-motd-login-message-in-debian-and-ubuntu/

```
sudo mkdir -p /etc/update-motd.d
sudo cat > /etc/update-motd.d/10date <<'EOF'
#!/bin/sh
echo
echo echo "Current date and time: $(date)"
EOF

sudo chmod a+x /etc/update-motd.d/*
```

It will show up in the next login.

Comment: You probably have to disable the static motd file prior to that, as stated in the very tutorial you've provided. Executing this without altering anything else will fail.

Answer (score 0):

For **Centos 7** I suggest using dynamic MOTD with my updated PAM package to have `update-motd.d` feature from Ubuntu.

Install with:

```
yum install https://github.com/gdubicki/centos-pam-with-update-motd/releases/download/1.1.8-1022.3/pam-1.1.8-1022.el7.x86_64.rpm
```

Use with:

1. Delete the default static `/etc/motd`.
2. Make SSHD not show the static MOTD with lines `PrintMotd   no`, `Banner      none`, `UsePAM      yes` (and optionally `PrintLastLog no`) in your `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` & reload `sshd` service.
3. Add this line to your `/etc/pam.d/sshd`: `session    optional     pam_motd.so motd=/run/motd.dynamic`.
4. Add your script to `/etc/update-motd.d`:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Current date and time: $(date)"
```

...as `/etc/update-motd.d/10time` file for example, with permissions to be read and executed by root.

Please see https://github.com/gdubicki/centos-pam-with-update-motd for the most up to date info.